# .MoveNext very slow on DAO recordset

Tags: sql, ms-access, dao

I have a DAO recordset that opens the following query:

```
SELECT sd.pointnumber
FROM (sdn INNER JOIN sd ON sdn.filename=sd.filename) 
INNER JOIN o ON sd.oID = o.id
WHERE o.id = [oID] 
And sdn.Line <>  [sdnLine];
```

Table `sd` has about 500,000 records and 30 columns, table `sdn` has about 5000 records and 4 columns.  Table `O` has 6 records and 12 columns.

I open the recordset with:

```
Dim qdf As QueryDef
Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("oSdSdn2")
qdf.Parameters("oID") = oID
qdf.Parameters("sdnLine") = line
Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenForwardOnly)
```

When I have the database open as the only user, the first time I call `.MoveNext` on `rs`, it takes 1-2 minutes to execute; after that, each `.MoveNext` happens in less than a second.  When there are multiple users in the database, every `.MoveNext` takes 1-2 minutes.

Tables are already indexed on `sdn.Line`, `o.id`, and `sd.oID`.

I tried structuring the query differently in the hopes of reducing the total number of rows to process:

```
select pointnumber from
(select pointnumber,filename from sd where oID=[oID]) sd
inner join
sdn
on
sd.filename=sdn.filename
where
sdn.line<>[sdnLine]
```

This didn't change the time at all.  Is there any way to speed up this query, especially if there are multiple users?

Answer (score 0):

It's not your query. It's your table. Your filters are on the smaller tables, so index are not required for them. However, your big table `sd` would need an index on `filename`, based on how you use it your query.